# Cant downgrade SFDX to previous version 7.181.1 for scratch org script created by team

Tags: metadata, cli, sfdx-error, upgrade, deprecation

I need to downgrade to this version(7.181.1) as the whole team uses it for a scratch org script. I've tried using the most previous one I can find 7.199.2 and the most recent 7.209.6.

Either one will cause me to fail the metadata deployment to the new scratch org on the line:

`<searchResultsAdditionalFields xsi:nil="true"/>`

With the Error:

**Error parsing file: Attribute name "xsi:nil" associated with an element type "searchResultsAdditionalFields" must be followed by the ' = ' character.**

I've tried just about everything in this documentation: [Install Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_olderversions)

If anyone could tell me how to revert to a deprecated version or belive I am missing something else, I'm all ears.

Comment: Are you using the binary or npm package?

Comment: I tried both. I wasnt able to revert any farther than 7.199.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into a similar issue with `<searchResultsAdditionalFields xsi:nil="true"/>` its an old bug. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000R0raQAC

This tag gets created in the metadata when a search layout field was added to an object that had its tab removed. I believe it try's to label the field as null. Either way the cli version I was using caught the issue where as the older versions my colleagues are using did not. The fix was just to remove all the data inside the `<searchLayouts>` section since they are no longer being used.